# Jquery String Replace Can't add html element before and after

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

This is my jquery script that replace string to new string:

```
$("*").contents().each(function() {
if(this.nodeType == 3)
    this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace("1.(800).123.1234", "new");
});
```

working example : http://jsfiddle.net/webdesignerart/eKRGT/

but i want to add before and after to string html element like **new**

when i do this :

```
  this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace("1.(800).123.1234", "<b>new</b>");
```

The Result comes:

```
<b>new</b>
```

I want output this: **new**

i want to allow html tags during replacement.

is jquery `.append` work with this.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the contents of a `TextNode` element which is always just **text**. To make the text bold, you will need to create another element, `b` which wraps around the `TextNode`. One approach is to use the `wrap()` from jQuery:

```
$("*").contents().each(function() {
    var me = this;
    if(this.nodeType == 3)
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace("1.(800).123.1234", function(a){
            $(me).wrap('<b />');
            return "new";            
        });
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/eLkZp/

Comment: That's going to make the entire node bold, not just the new.. http://jsfiddle.net/eLkZp/18/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("*").contents().each(function() {
    var me = this;
    if(this.nodeType == 3 
       && this.nodeValue.indexOf("1.(800).123.1234")>-1){

        $(this).replaceWith(this.nodeValue.replace("1.(800).123.1234", "<b>new</b>"));  
    }        
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eLkZp/20/

Basically replace the text node rather than just the text within it.

You should really consider if there's some way to narrow down that original filter though.  Parsing your entire page is generally a bad idea.